# Is there any way to access denominator of a fraction in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, fractions

Is there any way to access the denominator in a fraction in Python 2?

For example, I have a variable:

> x = fractions.Fraction(4,1)

And I want to access its denominator. How do I do that?

Comment: I was going to give you a hard time about not reading [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html), but I was appalled to find out that the documentation does not mention how to get the denominator (or numerator, for that matter)!  It seems like a **huge** oversight.  If a python developer happens by this page, please note that this really needs to be added to the `fractions` documentation.

Comment: FYI, I did read the `fractions` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) before asking here.

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out in my comment the documentation is not helpful (it usually is very helpful, that's why I'm so surprised).  I made that comment to point that out to others so they would not assume you didn't read the docs (as I had initially assumed till I saw the docs were not helpful).

Comment: [A link to the fractions.py source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py) is given in the `fractions` documentation, but you would have to understand what the `@property` decorator does (and how classes are written) to have figured out how to access the denominator.  *Technically* the docs author could argue that the information is there, but for a user new to the language it is **a)** not obvious to look there and **b)** difficult (or impossible if the user is new enough) to understand so it is still of no help.

Comment: It looks like they finally added `numerator` and `denominator` to the [python 3.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/fractions.html).  I doubt it will be back-ported to python 2.7, though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction(1,2)
>>> a.denominator
2
```

Additionally Python's `help()` method can be very useful to determine exactly what methods and properties exist for an object. In the example above you could get a help description for the `Fraction` object by `help(Fraction)` or `help(a)` in an interpreter session.

Comment: Oh, and I was trying a.denominator(). Did not realise the parentheses would not come. Thanks!

Comment: The denominator and numerator are properties of the `Fraction` object and not methods.

Comment: @nisargshah95 I'm sure it was giving a message like "int object is not callable".  That means that python thought you were trying to call an int like a function, i.e. adding the parentheses.  When you get that message, it means you are adding parentheses when you aren't supposed to.

Comment: Yes I did get `int object not callable` error. Thanks a lot for the clarification.